# Insert into SQL Server from Django View

Tags: python, django-views

--Need help with the syntax for inserting into SQL Server Table from django view.

Getting the below error:

('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'userid'.
(207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
[SQL Server]Invalid column name 'val1'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'val2'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'result'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'fname'. (207); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'lname'. (207)")

```
def add_view(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    val1 = float(request.POST['num1'])
    val2 = float(request.POST['num2'])
    result = val1 + val2      
    print("First name coming from the usercheck_view :: ", first_name)
    print("Last name coming from the usercheck_view :: ", last_name)
    print("Userid name coming from the usercheck_view :: ", userid)
    print("This is the value of val1 :: ", val1 )
    print("This is the value of val2 :: ", val2 )
    print("This is the value of result :: ", result )
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO datatable (userid, num1, num2, result) 
        VALUES ( userid, val1,val2,result ) 
        SELECT userid from userstable where first_name = fname and last_name = lname")
return render(request, 'addnum/home.html')
```

Comment: `val1`, `val2` etc. are local Python variables.  The SQL statement doesn't know anything about them.

Comment: check out string formatting

Comment: Thanks John and drum for your comments.